# Jframe not showing all contents when loaded in another computer

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

Am using GroupLayout to code my GUI application. The issue am having is that:

1) My PC Resolution is 1490 * 900. When I run the GUI, all contents are displayed clearly.

2) Now on my laptop (Resolution is 1366 * 768), when I run the same GUI, all contents are not being shown, am trying to resize it, but in vain.

**How can I make all the contents fit on the GUI on my laptop?**

The GUI codes are too long, am showing only the main parts:

```
static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
static int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();//Get Resolution of Screen
static int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

public Menu_Modifications_Single() {
     setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Menu_Modifications_Single.class.getResource("/Images/bug-red.png")));
    setTitle("Automated Bug Processing");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, width,height);//Get Screen Resolution Of Monitor Automatically
    setResizable(true);

    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);//Automatically Maximize JFrame Upon Loading
```

I tried the pack() but it does not seem to work.

Comment: There is a issue `setResizble`.  If I remember properly, you should set this AFTER the frame is made visible.  It sounds like you're not using any layout managers, which would help resolve this kind of issue.

Comment: Don't use `getScreenSize`, it won't take into account things like the task/dock bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pack()`, but after you add all the components to your frame. Then after that use the `setSize` or `setBounds` methods. So first add all your components, then call `pack()`, then finally set the size. See if that works.

EDIT:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

Comment: hmm. Try not using static and not casting getWidth to an int. See edited answer. Also in your code I can't seem to see setVisible(true)?

Comment: Again same thing. the code has set visible to true..It is displaying the Menu, but the bottom part of it gets cropped.

Comment: Using `getScreenSize` may not take into account things like the task/dock bars.  `setExtendedState` is a more appropriate method